# Iphone of friends as test devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

actually I am working on my first app. I use my ipad and my iphone as test devices but I would like to give my apps to my friends so they can test them. When I register their devices is there a way they can download the beta versions of the apps? Or can I only install the app using Xcode with a device directly connected to the mac.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: in another choice u have installed the ipa in w/o connected to the mac

Comment: Bit more effort but if it is only for downloading you could stick it on a server and give them a link to download it from. Have a look at OTA (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505-CH1-SW1) Maybe do a little bit of research into and how to implement it (It really isn't hard to implement) don't just read that document it doesn't give an easy way to implement but it's a starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **testflight** (available in itunes connect under pre-release of your application). Works on iOS8+ only.

Comment: Well yes the testflight on itunesconnect only works on iOS8 but you could still use the old https://testflightapp.com/ for older versions of iOS, though it is old now and Apple could get rid any day now.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your ipa file to http://diawi.com and after successful uploading you will get a link open the link in safari and you will be asked to install the app.  Note that to install ipa through Diawi you must create ipa file with provisioning profile and that provisioning profile must contain your device UDID. Hope this helps. :)